# how to replace null value from database with another string value present in same column columns in python?

Tags: python, lambda, user-defined-functions

Here We have one data frame
Which contains avengers hero names, and key columns in a data frame.
There are some rows that have a null name but the same name has a primary key assigned. I need to fill the Blanks with the key value if it is blank in the same database.

**Example-:** From image>
Index = 0 = key = 11 = Caption America.**Another**
Index = 9 = key = 11 = "". In this case index 9 is Null but We know we can place ***Caption America*** in that place from the same data frame.

I have a database that has thousands of rows which has similar kind of data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByEOm.png)

If there is any "Null" value in the database and its respective key and value are present in the data frame that should be Replaced by its Key and value.

**How we can implement this using python?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByEOm.png)